# How to open a protected Excel File with ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, excel, protected, closedxml, xlsm

Is it possible to use ClosedXML to open an Excel file protected with a password? And if so, how?

I tried using Interop but it's very slow.

```
Using Interop.Excel
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: "c:\TEST\MyFileProtected.xlsx", ReadOnly: true, Password: "PASSWORD");
```

I also tried with ClosedXML with no success

```
string path = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();

var wb = new XLWorkbook(path);
wb.Unprotect("password");
```

I'm getting the error

> "File contains corrupted data" creating the XLWorkbook object.

Comment: looks like you cant: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/07/17/overview-of-protected-office-open-xml-documents/

Comment: Have you checked the [`Unprotect()`](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/cacfb263adb8971a807fe18d2687af15f850d231/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook.cs#L1002) method?

Comment: @Progman
I'm getting "File contains corrupted data"

I tried this code:
string path = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
var wb = new XLWorkbook(path);
wb.Unprotect("password");
It seams that is not possible... :(
Stuck in interop loading an Excel file with 4 columns and 1000 rows in 10s or more...

Comment: How did you create the workbook? Can you open it with Excel without getting any errors about corrupt content?

Comment: Yes I can open it with Excel without getting any errors. 
Erverything it's ok with the file.
The file was created in Excel 2016.
I'm trying to develop in c# should I go back to VBA.
Microsoft.Interop.Excel is not an option... Too Slow.

Answer (score 3):

Password protection to enable/disable the opening of a file is not supported with ClosedXML/OpenXML. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/07/17/overview-of-protected-office-open-xml-documents/

You can only lock the structure and windows of an OpenXML document and that is indeed what the `wb.Protect()` method does.

That said, ClosedXML supports only the legacy protection methods. Newer protection methods and password hashing algorithms, introduced in Excel 2013, are not supported yet. Refer to https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/866